# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((Student Number = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND Name IS NULL) OR (Name = ?)))'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Error says:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((Student Number
>   = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND Name IS NULL) OR (Name = ?)))

The Code Is:

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    ds.Tables("BSorg Members").Rows(inc).Item(1) = tbStudentNumber.Text()
    ds.Tables("BSorg Members").Rows(inc).Item(1) = tbName.Text()

    da.Update(ds, "BSorg Members")
  MsgBox("Data updated")
End Sub
```

Where tbStudentNumber.Text() shows the data "Student Number" on access and shows the "Name".

What does it mean and how do i solve it?

Comment: Your SQL query would actually help. There is the error.

Comment: is there something wrong with this query?
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source = C:/Users/user/Desktop/BSorgMembershipDatabase.mdb"
        Con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        Con.Open()

        MsgBox("Database is now open")

        sql = "SELECT * FROM Members"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Con)
        da.Fill(ds, "BSorg Members")

        Con.Close()

Comment: That is not the query where the error occurs.

Comment: Please don't put code in a comment.  Edit your question to add code.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it appears that you are trying to pass a field name to the query as a parameter. If so, then that won't work. Query parameters only apply to field (column) *values*, not field *names*.

To illustrate, the following C# code will *not* work:

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=C:\__tmp\main.accdb;"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Table1 WHERE ? = 1", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "ID");
        int n = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

In this case it fails with

> Data type mismatch in critera expression

However, this code works fine

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data Source=C:\__tmp\main.accdb;"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", con))
    {
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "ID");
        int n = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss this

```
ds.Tables("BSorg Members").Rows(inc).Item(0) = tbStudentNumber.Text
ds.Tables("BSorg Members").Rows(inc).Item(1) = tbName.Text
```

Comment: matzone I already tried changing it to that.. :( still the same results